# Graph API - Creating new photo album for facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create an album on my Facebook app using the Graph API. It's quite easy to create an album for a user account. We just need to have a user access token and send a post request for

`https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/albums`

`{
  name :'my USER album'
}`

It seems to be logical sending the same post request for app:
`https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/albums`

`{
  name :'my APP album'
}`

However it doesn't work. I use the app token which I get from:
[access token tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

Does anybody know how can I do this?

Comment: are you trying rather to create a photo album on the **PAGE** you app is in?

Comment: I got **"message": "(#100) Invalid ID for album owner", "type": "OAuthException"**

Comment: Same message here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution. It's quite wird, but what can I do.

Only a user who is an admin of the app can create new albums and photos. If you meet this criterion your app needs to request the user for one more permission: `manage_pages`.

After this you can request `http://graph.facebook.com/ADMIN_USER_ID/accounts`. There you will get an array of all pages managed by this user. Find en element which contains your `APP_ID`. The same element contains an `access_token` which is required to perform *create album* and upload photo actions.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple solution detailed on the facebook [Authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).(Scroll down to "App Login")

You have to query this url :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
 grant_type=client_credentials
```

the response will be an access token that you can use to perform actions on behalf of you app.

Comment: I tried it too. It return exactly the same access token as this one from [access token tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).
It returns the following error.
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid ID for album owner", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Use page access token instead of user access token,for some operation we require page access token.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the new API (GraphQL 2.9 as of today) is no more able to create albums dedicated to the Application.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/

I have opened a question here : [Create photo albums in a Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010398/create-photo-albums-in-a-facebook-app)